# What's Xiaomi Mi Store app's page intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, xiaomi

I'm developer of an Android [library](https://github.com/RankoR/android-smart-rate) for rating apps, which asks user if he likes an app, and if he wants to rate the app redirects it to the app store.

Does someone know, what's Xiaomi Mi Store's launch intent for redirecting user right to the given app?

For example, for Google Play it's:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
    data = Uri.parse(
            "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.android")
    setPackage("com.android.vending")
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, finally I've got an answer from the Xiaomi Developer support:

> The link below could be used to open GetApps and take to the app page，on condition that the user has already installed GetApps.
> Link:  mimarket://details?id=packagename&back=true|false&ref=refstr&startDownload=true
> Note: you could replace the package name with yours

So I guess we have to use this code:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
   .apply {
      data = Uri.parse("mimarket://details?id=com.example.android&back=true|false&ref=refstr&startDownload=true")
}
```

Comment: Any idea how to get the same for Vivo, Oppo, Samsung, Huawei etc stores?

Comment: @Hemanth try to reach their developer support